# Job not executing

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, sql-server-agent

Hi i have a set of SSIS packages which i have deployed in my local db i.e. in msdb.

I have created a job to execute the package but when i run the job i am getting the following error.

```
Message
The job failed.  Unable to determine if the owner (ICREATEBI\jayant.shinde) of job BFS_Load has server access (reason: Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'ICREATEBI\jayant.shinde', error code 0x54b. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 15404)).
```

I have admin rights on my system as well as the database.

Comment: Your Sql Server Agent account needs permissions on that server to execute the job. Go to sql server configuration manager and check the sqlagent account and make sure it has permission to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following links for this issue.

http://armordba.wordpress.com/2013/04/29/executing-a-sql-server-2012-ssis-package-with-a-proxy-account-with-least-rights-across-domains/

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/de4727ee-181c-43b2-98b3-24382a4fbf2a/using-proxy-accounts-to-run-ssis-packages-by-sql-agent?forum=sqlintegrationservices

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2163/running-a-ssis-package-from-sql-server-agent-using-a-proxy-account/

These links refer to steps about creating a proxy credential and running the SQL Server Agent Job using this proxy credential.

Comment: Please don't just link to forums to provide answers. Can you summarize how to deal with this problem in the answer, and provide links for support?